# Resize extracted photo from active directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, active-directory

I am able to retrieve thumbnail photo from active directory. But I am not able to fit it in the place I want to as the size of the extracted image seems small.

Code used :

```html
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo "".base64_encode($_SESSION['photo']).""; ?>" alt="profile-sample4" class="profile" style="width:130px ;height: 130px;"/>
```

Is there a way to resize the extracted image?

Comment: Uhh... You have CSS in there, sizing it already, don't you? Just change the 130px to whatever you want

Comment: Its not happening .I tried inline css already before posting the question.Anyways,thanks.

Comment: Maybe try using HTML attributes `width=''` and `height=''` on your `<img>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code here :

```html
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search52");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess something override your css,  First use

```
 class="profile myimg"
```

in your tag image then remove "" based on Andrew's edit. In fact I believe that could be a problem because you use " inside ".

```html
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($_SESSION['photo']) ?>" alt="profile-sample4" class="profile myimg" />
```

And this will be your css class:

```
.myimg{
  width: 130px !important;
  height: 130px !important;
}
```

Comment: its not going to work.But the issue here is that the image is extracted from active directory,its not an image save locally.I have tried doing what you said.Anyways,thanks.

Comment: @jane I don't think the source of the image is your problem , Another thing is removing "" inside your src "", it might be the problem.

Comment: @jane, what does your $_SESSION['photo'] look like?